# Photoshop elements 11

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am comparing prices of Photoshop Elements 11 for our new iMac. Some of the ads say 4 gb space needed for download. Others are less money but only need 1.5 gb. Are there different versions of elements 11 out there? Why the big diff in space needed?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of different version of PSE.

Although, [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/fr/products/photoshop-elements/tech-specs.html) says 4GB of disk space needed. The 1.5 Gig you might saw seems to correspond to the size of the installer.